# Facing Duplication Error In SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm working on my final year project which is a School management system, there are many tasks in this project but i'm working on attendance module at this time, I have created a sql server table which contains four columns :

1. Student Name
2. Class Name
3. Attendance Status (Column name is "Status")
4. Date (Current Date for attendance)

and then I created a stored procedure. This stored procedure will get student name, class name and attendance status as parameter and then adds this to attendance table which shows if student is present on specified date or absent,
the date column have default value of `getDate()`.

The stored procedure first checks if the student attendance is already present in the table for current date, then it changes the attendance status column value rather than adding a new row, and if the student attendance is not present for current date then stored procedure will add new row,

**BUT**......

My procedure is not working as expected, when I first pass parameters, it adds the new row, when I again pass the same parameters, then it should replace attendance status column but it again adds a new row.

But the third time, when I pass same parameter, then it works correctly and replaces status column value, so in this case I have 2 rows for the same student but I need only one row.

Please guide me what is the problem in my stored procedure -- here is the code:

```
create procedure spAttend_Stu
    @Name nvarchar(200),
    @C_Name nvarchar(50),
    @Status nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    if ((select count(*) 
         from tbl_Attend_Stu 
         where Student_Name = @Name 
           and Date = (select convert(date, getdate()))) > 1)
       update tbl_Attend_Stu 
       set [Status] = @Status 
       where [Date] = (select convert(date, getdate()))
    else
       insert into tbl_Attend_Stu (Student_Name, Class_Name, Status)
       values (@Name, @C_Name, @Status)
end
```

EDIT :

Here is my table definition..see this screenshot:

[image: Table structure]

and I'm passing this value as an example

```
spAttend_Stu 'Ammar', 'BSCS', 'Absent'
```

I'm running the same query again, but result is not as expected

view this screenshot for example execution

[image: example execution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you posted the schema constructor syntax for your `tbl_Attend_Stu` so we could see the field `Date` and its default value.  However, there are a couple of initial thoughts for you to check (Note: without seeing examples of what is being passed in, and what values are in your table it is hard to know for sure) :

1. Perhaps the value of `@Name` is not what you expect it to be when it is getting passed into your SP.  If the value varies, even slightly, then the first IF statement logic won't find the student and another insert will happen.  One potential fix could be to ensure the `@Name` and `@C_Name` variables are trimmed properly; if they are being passed into the SP with spaces, then it might be your culprit.
2. If you default value configuration for `Date` is not setup properly then no date will get inserted when the `INSERT` statement is called.  Try explicitly setting `Date` within the `INSERT` statement to `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())` and see if this gives you what you expect.
3. I found other issues with spots in your code.  For example, you're missing a second condition in your `UPDATE` statement logic to only update the row for the specific student.  The way you have it now will update the `Date` field for every row in the table.

I rewrote your logic here to make it a bit more readable, and fix the error I mentioned above, and small other syntax typos:

```
create procedure spAttend_Stu
@Name nvarchar(200),
@C_Name nvarchar(50),
@Status nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

IF
( 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM   tbl_Attend_Stu 
     WHERE  Student_Name = @Name 
        AND [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
    )
    >= 1
)
    UPDATE tbl_Attend_Stu 
    SET [Status] = @Status 
    WHERE   Student_Name = @Name
        AND [Date] = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

ELSE

    INSERT INTO tbl_Attend_Stu
        (Student_Name, Class_Name, Status)
    VALUES
        (RTRIM(LTRIM(@Name)), RTRIM(LTRIM(@C_Name)), @Status)

END
```

Comment: thank you very much bro :) I have tried your suggestion but the problem still exists, i have edited my question and added table definition screen shot and example which I am using at this time.. please have a look :)

Comment: Can you also provide a screenshot of what your table looks like after running your stored procedure when running it 3 times with the example values you provided?

Comment: ok bro i have added a screen shot after execution please check

Comment: oh, this is easy.  Your logic says `> 1`.  What happens if there is exactly `1` already present?  In this case, if there is 1 already present it will insert another one, then there will be 2, which is greater than 1, which is why it works correctly on the 3rd try.  So change your `>` to `>=` and it will work as expected

Comment: ooooo let me try ... just a second

Comment: yess... its working as expected :) thank you very much bro... a bundle of thanks :)